# For linear transformations represented as matrices, columns represent the image of the basis vectors for R$^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

For linear transformations represented as matrices, columns represent the image of the basis vectors for R$^n$.

Can someone please explain the above statement? I am familiar all of the terms used, but I do not understand what it means by 'the columns represent the image of the basis vectors for R$^n$. Also, please provide examples to make it clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the matrix of a linear map $u$ in a given basis $(e_1,\dots e_n)$, the elements of the 1st column are the coordinates of $u(e_1)$, those of the 2nd column are the coordinates of $u(e_2)$, &c., the elements of the last column are the coordinates of $u(e_n)$, in the given basis.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 1  \\
0  \\
0 
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 1  \\
4  \\
7 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The columns are the images of the standard basis. They span the image.